# Why does the Graph API return question mark cover photos for my albums on first login and proper images on subsequent logins?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the FB javascript driver for the Graph API to allow a user to pick photos from their Facebook account. The first time they connect they're prompted to login with:

```
FB.login(function(res) {
    if (res.status == 'connected') {
        auth = res.authResponse; // cache auth response
        getAlbums();
    }
});
```

If successful, I cache the returned auth object and immediately fetch the user's albums with:

```
function getAlbums() {
    FB.api('/me/albums', function(res) {
        albums = res.data;
    });
}
```

Using the returned object I iterate over the albums and display their `cover_photo` with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{album.cover_photo}}/picture?type=normal&access_token={{auth.accessToken}}
```

The first time a user logs in, all the cover photos are the question mark icons. However, if the user refreshes, or returns to the page, the app re-authenticates, recognizes the user is already logged in, and displays the proper cover_photo thumbnails.

How can I get newly authenticated users to be able to see their cover photos?

Comment: The cover image is a question mark when there are no images in your album. I think for some reason, your object is not being loaded properly for the first time authentication. Are you using callbacks properly in your code?

Comment: I've reproduce this issue with an empty access token, https://graph.facebook.com/10200952202073231/picture?type=normal&access_token=
Try to console.log the param you get on the FB.login callback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you have not subscribed to **authResponseChange** [event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

The following piece of simple code does the same that you are looking for-

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
var access_token = "";
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({
        appId      : '<APP-ID>',
        status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true 
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
    {
        access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        if (response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            FetchUserPhotos();
        } 
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
            FB.login('scope: user_photos');
        } 
        else 
        {
            FB.login('scope: user_photos');
        }
    });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function FetchUserPhotos() 
{
    FB.api('/me/albums', function(response) 
    {
        var albums = response.data;
        for(var i=0; i<albums.length; i++)
        {
            var album = albums[i];
            if(album.cover_photo != undefined)
            {
               FB.api("/"+album.cover_photo+"?access_token="+access_token, function(cover_photo)
               {
                   console.log(cover_photo.source);
               });       
               //console.log("https://graph.facebook.com/"+album.cover_photo+"/picture?type=normal&access_token="+access_token);
            }
         }          
    });
}
</script>

<fb:login-button scope="user_photos" show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: Interesting regarding the auth events, however, the issue isn't retrieving the albums, it's retrieving the cover_photos from those albums the first time the user logs into the app. Once they return the cover_photos show up as normal.

Comment: Ok, but the cover photos are also fetched in one go, right? I've edited the code to get the cover photos and its working good

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm getting images back, but they're showing the question mark "default" image so a simple console.log may not be enough to prove it's working.

Comment: Did you tried opening the links from console.log? All images were opening fine when i tried

Comment: I think the better solution would be to fetch the image url directly, since using access_token in the image url is not a good idea. So, you should use `FB.api("/"+album.cover_photo)` - edited the answer. pls check

Comment: I will. I've been bogged down and couldn't test your implementations until today.